# Standard form of a matrix under similar transformation?

Tags: matrices

Real symmetric matrices $S_{ij}$ can always be put in a standard diagonal form $s_i\delta_{ij}$ under an orthogonal transformation. Similarly, real antisymmetric matrices $A_{ij}$ can always be put in a standard *band* diagonal form with diagonal matrix entries $a_i\pmatrix{0 &1\\-1 &0}$ (with a $0$ diagonal entry when the dimension of the matrix is odd), again under an orthogonal transformation.

For a more general matrix $M^i_{\;j}$, I'd like to know if there is a *standard* form it can be put in using some similarity transformation. By standard form I mean a form which is not necessarily diagonal, but common sense would say is the *simplest* form a matrix can be put in.

Comment: [Jordan form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form), although the basis is not necessarily orthonormal.

Comment: @angryavian thanks for the comment. I consider that the answer to my question, so if you add an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Jordan form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form); any complex matrix is similar to a Jordan matrix (but the basis might not be orthonormal). A real matrix might be similar to a Jordan matrix with complex diagonal entries; if you need everything to be real, this can be remedied with "real Jordan blocks" as discussed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form#Real_matrices).